# Java regex for $ replacement

Tags: java, regex

Question 1.
I am trying to change my string from "(a) to (b) the line is correct"  to "(a) 2 (b) the line is correct". for that i am using this code but it not working as my requirement

```
strtargetsentence=strtargetsentence_.replaceAll"([\(]([A-Za-z0-9])[\)][ ](to|and|or)[ ][\(]([A-Za-z0-9])[\)])","([\(]([A-Za-z0-9])[\)][ ](2|&|aur)[ ][\(]([A-Za-z0-9])[\)])"
```

Similarly i also want to do these combination

```
(a) to (b)--->(a) 2 (b)
(b) to (e)--->(b) & (e)  
(1) to (2)--->(1) aur (2)
```

Question 2.
Silimarly for these combination also i am trying this with following code

```
[a] we are going ---->[a] we are going
1)we are going---->1)we are going

strtargetsentence=strtargetsentence_.replaceAll("([\\[|\\(])?([0-9A-Za-z]+)([\\.|\\)|\\]?])", "$1$2$3");
```

Comment: Please clean up your question. It is hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write several regex replacements. For question 1 that could result in three replace statements like these:

```
String strtargetsentence_ = "(a) to (b)";
String pattern1 = "(\\(\\w\\)) to (\\(\\w\\))";
String pattern2 = "(\\(\\w\\)) and (\\(\\w\\))";
String pattern3 = "(\\(\\w\\)) or (\\(\\w\\))";
String strtargetsentence=strtargetsentence_.replaceAll(pattern1,"$1 2 $2")
        .replaceAll(pattern2,"$1 & $2")
        .replaceAll(pattern3,"$1 aur $2");
System.out.println(strtargetsentence);
```

A replacement for your second question could be the following:

```
String strtargetsentence=strtargetsentence_.replaceAll("(\\[?\\w)(\\]|\\))( ?.*)", "$1$2$3");
```

Comment: thanks for reply.but got solution like this
("([\\[|\\(])?(\\S+)([\\.|\\)|\\]?])", $1$2$3).whether this is correct??
but for first question i want single expression.